# cannot convert JSON response from windows-1253 to utf8

Tags: php, .net, json, guzzle

I'm trying to parse a JSON response from a web service I have no control over.

These are the headers

[image]

This is the body I see in php with sensitive parts hidden

[image]

I'm using guzzle http client to send the request and to retrieve the response

If I try to decode it directly I receive an empty object so I'm assuming a conversion is needed  so I am trying to convert the response contents like this

`json_decode(iconv($charset, 'UTF-8', $contents))`

or

`mb_convert_encoding($contents, 'UTF-8', $charset);`

both of which throw an exception.

`Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from 'windows-1253' to 'UTF-8' is not allowed in Client.php on line 205`

`Warning: mb_convert_encoding(): Illegal character encoding specified in Client.php on line 208`

I've used this piece of code successfully before but I can't understand why it fails now.

Sending the same request using POSTMAN correctly retrieves the data without broken characters and it seems to show the same headers and body received.

I'm updating based on comments.

`mb_detect_encoding($response->getBody())`  -> UTF-8

`mb_detect_encoding($response->getBody->getContents())` -> ASCII

`json_last_error_msg` -> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Additionally as a trial and error attempt I tried all iconv encodings to see if any could convert it to utf-8 without an error to detect the encoding using this one

```
        private function detectEncoding($str){
        $iconvEncodings = [...]
        $finalEncoding = "unknown";
        foreach($iconvEncodings as $encoding){
            try{
                iconv($encoding, 'UTF-8', $str);
                return $encoding;
            }
            catch (\Exception $exception){
                continue;
            }
        }
        return $finalEncoding;
    }
```

Apparently no encoding worked and everything gave the same exception. I'm assuming the problem is with retrieving the response json correctly via guzzle and not with iconv itself. It can't be that it's not any of the 1000+ ones.

Some more info with CURL

I just retried the same payload using CURL

```
  /**
     * @param $options
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function makeCurlRequest($options)
    {

        $payload = json_encode($options);
        // Prepare new cURL resource
        $ch = curl_init($this->softoneurl);

        curl_setopt_array($ch, [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,  // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",     // handle compressed
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "test", // name of client
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,   // set referrer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,    // time-out on response
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
        ]);

        // Set HTTP Header for POST request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))
        );

        // Submit the POST request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Close cURL session handle
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

I received the exact same string and the exact same results with converting it. Perhaps an option I'm missing?

Apparently there's something wrong with iconv itself in the environment and it's not application specific. Running the following code via SSH

```
php -r "var_dump(iconv('Windows-1253', 'UTF-8', 'test'));"
```

yields

```
PHP Notice:  iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `Windows-1253' to `UTF-8' is not allowed in Command line code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0
PHP   2. iconv(*uninitialized*, *uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) Command line code:1
Command line code:1:
bool(false)
```

Perhaps some dependency is missing

Comment: What does `json_last_error_msg()` return?

Comment: Also, what does [mb_detect_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) say the encoding is? Do you know it's not UTF-8?

Comment: I've just updated my question with what I'm seeing. It's very confusing.

Comment: Guzzle is not reading the result correctly.

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding()` does not [support](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php) Windows-1253 but `iconv()` should work fine. JSON must be encoded as UTF-8 (it isn't optional) so you need to get it fixed before you use JSON functions. I suggest you fix one thing at a time. For instance, save the response to a file and then figure out if it actually uses Windows-1253 and whether `iconv()` can fix it.

Comment: BTW, `mb_detect_encoding()` doesn't do what its name suggests.

Comment: Yes I do understand that json needs to be utf8 however the multimillion company that creates the web service doesn't and doesn't really care but I have to use it :(. Therefore I'm at a problematic situation. I'll try saving it to a file and test and report back. What's puzzling me is that I have 3 more applications that use the exact same way for the exact same web service and they load so I can't understand what's happening that's blocking it from working.

Comment: I just saved it to a file and the encoding is indeed windows-1253 and the contents display fine.

Comment: I presume it actually contains raw Greek characters. Then try file_get_contents() plus iconv() .

Comment: Just did, file_get_contents and iconv still fails with the same error Wrong charset, conversion from 'windows-1253' to 'UTF-8' is not allowed in

Comment: At least they are partially making up for their non-compliance with standards concerning the character encoding for JSON with compliance with standards concerning the indicating the character encoding of text-based HTTP bodies in general.

Comment: Yes, it would be very hard to detect the encoding otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About 14 hours of troubleshooting later I'm able to answer my own question correctly. In my case since this was running in the context of a CLI command, it caused an issue due to missing libraries. Basically the CLI php binary didn't have access to some libraries iconv needed.

More specifically the gconv libraries. 
In my case in Debian 9 it was located in

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv`

and this folder contains a lot of libraries for each encoding used. 
A good way to understand this is if you run in a system you have root access the command

`strace iconv -f <needed_encoding> -t utf-8`

It will yield a lot of folders that iconv tries to access including the gconv folder and will point you to the location of the ones you need to include in your SSH environment. If you don't have access as root you have to ask your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$response = $guzzle->request('GET', $url);

$type = $response->getHeader('content-type');
$parsed = Psr7\parse_header($type);

$original_body = (string)$response->getBody();
$utf8_body = mb_convert_encoding($original_body, 'UTF-8', $parsed[0]['charset'] ?: 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I've already tried this exact example from the guzzle repository issues. Same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

For those who had the same issue there is a simpliest method to resolve it i know its 3 years later but u can also set some headers.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=windows-1253');
```

that solved my problem instantly.

Comment: If you check, the headers are already there in the response from the web service. However they're set to windows-1253 while JSON specs define that it should be UTF-8. That's the whole issue here. Since we cannot modify the headers to send the correct encoding for JSON,we have to convert it to read it or json_decode will jumble the characters.